# Selectize not working inside Bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js 0.10.1 with Bootstrap 3.0.1 in my project. When I have selectize combobox outside the collapsible Bootstrap panel, everything works great as you can see in the picture.
[image: working example]

Working code:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <select id="zastoj" placeholder="Razlog zastoja" class="demo-default selectized"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I have selectize combobox inside the collapsible panel, the combobox can not be opened/expanded on click, it looks like it's read-only.
[image: non-working example]

Non-working code:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Operacije</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <select id="zastoj2" placeholder="Razlog škarta" class="demo-default selectized"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I got it to work when I use Bootstrap 2.3.2 and selectize.js 0.9 in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tstancin/yaBPm/8/), but I can't get it to work with Bootstrap 3.1.1 and selectize.js 0.9 in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tstancin/bSq4X/). I even tried selectize 0.10.1, but no luck.

Can this be solved or is it some kind of version problem? I need to use Bootstrap 3.0+ in my project.

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I had a similar problem when `selectize` was initialized with the option:

```
dropdownParent: "body"
```

If you have this option in your selectize initialization, remove it.

Comment: Thanks. It was a great solution. You saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

The panel has the css style

```
overflow:hidden;
```

That is what keeps the selectize control from showing.  You can either hard code the style or add it to your stylesheet.

```
<section class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="overflow:visible;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Operacije</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <select id="zastoj2" placeholder="Razlog škarta" class="demo-default selectized"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

or in your stylesheet:

```
.panel, .panel-default, .panel-primary {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using selectize.js along with AngularJS, make sure the `<select>` is not inside a `<div ng-if="..."> ... </div>` cause it will not work. Instead, use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` instead. This also covers the scenario where a `<select>` is contained within a modal.

**Example:**

```
<!-- This won't work -->                                
<div ng-if="condition == true">
    <select id="my-selectize"></select>
</div>

<!-- This will work -->                             
<div ng-show="condition == true">
    <select id="my-selectize"></select>
</div>
```